# How to avoid CSS impact by a third party library?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a angular project which use a library called [smDateTimeRangePicker](https://github.com/mominsamir/smDateTimeRangePicker/) , it include the code below:

[Link Here](https://github.com/mominsamir/smDateTimeRangePicker/blob/master/dist/styles/picker.min.css#L170)

```
.action {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%; }
```

However, in my project, there is a code which also include `action` class

```
<div flex class="action cell">
```

And it is impacted by the CSS above, how to avoid it?

**This question considered about these points below:**

- There is a way that can avoid the CSS impact between project and library.
- The library uses a bad practice, it must avoid impacting project. It is a bug for the library and must be fixed.
- This impact usually happens, so I need to change my project to avoid the conflict

Comment: only way to get them both work is make one `.action` private and another public

Comment: hi Stef, use !important to override whatever rules the library has on the action class

Comment: follow CSS specificity rools to avoid such. https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/#article-header-id-0

Comment: Can't you use another class inside the project ?

Comment: @Weedoze use another class may cause a huge change of my project

Answer (score 0):

Rename your project action class to something else is the cleanest way. Else you have to resort to fixes that are considered bad practice like  !important, however these still get the job done.

Comment: What I am not sure is, if a project is impacted by third party, it is a good choice to change the project? In addition, it is hard to override the css, for example, which value you set for bottom to override the 0?

Comment: Ideally you know which third parties you are going to use and make sure you do not have any collisions prior. Renaming in this case is to have benign CSS free from hacks. I would do a rename for correctness sake and future maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

this happens to me quite frequently, so to solved it I just add one parent class to my page or that particular section

```
<div class="my-unique-class">

    ---
        <div class="action">
            ---
        </div>
    ---

</div> 

.my-unique-class .action {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: This piece of code is in the library so you cannot modify it.

Comment: in that case u need to either change ur class if possible or u need to use CSS specificity to overwrite that particular css

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid such kind of situation by increasing specificity of your css rules. 
There are multiple ways to do so:

1. Include all third party CSS files before your custom file so that css rules with same priority (In Your Case) can override the rule in third party CSS file.
2. Above solution should work in most of the cases, but there are chances that Third party CSS might come with higher priority orders, so you can increase weight of your css by adding class at your parent tag as:

```css
.parent > .action {
  / * Some CSS Code */
}
```

```html
<section class="parent">
  <div flex class="action cell"></div>
</section>
```

MDN has great article about CSS Specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your class name, you could make your styles unique to your element by doing:

```
.action.cell {

/*your styles here*/

}
```

By leaving out the space between action and cell you are saying that both classes are on the same element. Also, make sure you are loading your stylesheet after the 3rd party stylesheet so that your styles are being applied over theirs.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a CSS rule, you can use !important before semicolon:

```
background: black !important ;
```

It marks your rule as "important" and it cannot be changed with any CSS file.

Only inline CSS can overwrite it:

```
style="background: blue !important"
```